# Entity Framework 7 many to many join table get no record when insert

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert into a table that has many to many relationship with other table. The tables show as below:

[image]

The IDs are Primary key and has auto increment. I create the Database first, then use the command to scaffold/generate the entities. I didn't use the migration to update the database.

I want to insert a record into table `NOVEL` that have genres as the same time. Here is my code for insertion:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateNovelViewModel novelVM)
        {
            Novel novel = new Novel();
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    novel.NovelTitle = novelVM.NovelTitle;
                    novel.NovelCover = "";
                    novel.NovelDescription = novelVM.NovelDescription;
                    novel.AuthorId = novelVM.AuthorID;
                    novel.UserId = novelVM.UserID;

                    foreach(var genreId in novelVM.Genres)
                    {
                        var genre = new Genre();
                        novel.Genres.Add(genreId);
                    }

                    _context.Add(novel);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Không thể thêm.Hãy thử lại, nếu vấn đề còn tồn tại, liên hệ người có chuyên môn.");
                }
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Không thể thêm. Hãy thử lại, nếu vấn đề còn tồn tại, liên hệ người có chuyên môn.");
            }
            ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(_context.Authors, "AuthorId", "AuthorName", novelVM.AuthorID);
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserId", novelVM.UserID);
            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_context.Genres, "GenreId", "GenreName");
            return View(novel);
        }
```

The code run ok, a record is added to `NOVEL` successfully. But I don't know why the `NOVEL_GENRE` table got no record. I assume there is no id for `novel` at the time so it cannot insert into the join table?

Here is my `Novel.cs` entity:

```
public partial class Novel
{
    [Key]
    public int NovelId { get; set; }

    public string NovelTitle { get; set; } = null!;

    public string NovelDescription { get; set; } = null!;

    public string NovelCover { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime NovelDatePost { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public int NovelView { get; set; } = 1;

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; } = new List<Chapter>();

    public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<UserComment> UserComments { get; } = new List<UserComment>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserRating> UserRatings { get; } = new List<UserRating>();

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; } = new List<Genre>();
}
```

This is `Genre.cs` entity:

```
public partial class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public string GenreName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string GenreDescription { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Novel> Novels { get; } = new List<Novel>();
}
```

This is my View model `CreateNovelViewModel.cs`:

```
public class CreateNovelViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public String NovelTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String NovelDescription { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //public string NovelCover { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm just started with EF so I might use the function incorrectly. It will be appreciated if someone give some example for this. Thanks.

Comment: The table NOVEL_GENRE does not have primary key and entityframework will not recognise. You can either add primary key to the many-to-many table or else make entity framework know that it has a composite key i.e. combination of primary key 
Follow the link below to define composite key :
https://softdevpractice.com/blog/many-to-many-ef-core/

Comment: @VigneshPandi it has a PK - it is just a composite one, which makes sense in case of so called join entities.

Comment: `var genre = new Genre(); novel.Genres.Add(genreId);` looks a bit strange. I even wonder how it does compile. You are creating `Genre` instance and just throw it away. Though the first thing I would check would be  that `novelVM.Genres` is actually not empty (I'm quite sure it is).

Comment: @GuruStron I understand my mistake for that line. Just debugging my code and there is none item in my View Model at the loop. But when I check it at the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` there are items. I don't know where did my items go?

Comment: `Model.IsValid` is not relevant here unless you have somehow configured validations so the collection is required to have at least 1 element. I don't know how do you post things - seems that the problem is there, but when you will figure that out you will have another problem - either exception or new genres being created - you need to attach existing genres to context otherwise it will know nothing about them.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks a lot for the advice. I just found out I have to change my list into a primitive type for posting back. Referenced from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238877/17516799

Comment: @pilog yes, posting list of ids is far better approach in this case, but in general (have not worked with MVC for a bit) I think you can bind complex objects, but you will need to "add" them on the page in by field manner, (something like `EditorFor(m => m.Genres[i].GenreId)....` where `i` is from some `for` loop over the `Genres` collection)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GuruStron for guidelines. Here is my code after make some change.

I changed the ICollection to List because primitive type for Post back in `CreateNovelViewModel.cs`:

```
public class CreateNovelViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public String NovelTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String NovelDescription { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //public string NovelCover { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<int> GenreId { get; set; }
    }
```

In `Controller`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateNovelViewModel novelVM) {
...
                    List<int> list = novelVM.GenreId;
                    foreach (var genreId in list)
                    {
                        var genre = new Genre();
                        genre.GenreId = genreId;
                        novel.Genres.Add(genre);
                    }
                    _context.Novels.Attach(novel).State = EntityState.Added;
                    _context.Add(novel);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
...
}
```